# Ao alterar um Model, como refazer o Scaffolding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, scaffold

Tenho um model, chamado `CombustivelModels`, onde fiz um `Scaffolding` gerando o `Controller` e as `Views`, minha duvida é, ao fazer uma revisão nesse `Model`, tem como atualizar via `Scaffolding` o `Controller` e as `View`?

Model antigo:

```
public class CombustivelModels
{
    [Key]
    public int CombustivelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal km_inicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal km_final { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal litros { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
}
```

Model Revisado:

```
public class CombustivelModels
    {
    [Key]
    public int CombustivelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal km_inicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal km_final { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal litros { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal valor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que deletar o que já foi criado e criar novamente.

O ato de editar o model não alterado o que já foi criado.

Lembrando que a inclusão de uma anotação no model muda a forma como um `@Html.EditFor<>` monta o seu `textbox`, por exemplo.

Já a inclusão e exclusão de novos campos e relacionamentos não alteram a view.

**Atualizando**

Eu aconselho no seu caso editar a view na mão, depois que entender como a view funciona fica muito fácil de fazer, vale a pena fazer como forma de aprendizado e estudo